# Regular Expression FS00000

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression to match FS00000 were the 0s can be a number from 0-9. There can only be 5 numbers following the FS.

Comment: What language? Everyone is being forced to give generic answers, which may or may not be helpful to you.

Comment: @phone: ...There can only be 5 numbers .... Exactly 5 "{5}" or up to five? {1,5}, or none to 5? {0,5} or... or... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^FS\d{5}$
```

which matches the line start (`^` - you may not need this), then `FS`, then a digit `\d` 5 times `{5}`, then the line end `$` (again, you may not need this, but you'd then have to protect against a sixth digit following).

You don't specify which language/regexp, but the above is pretty generic.

EDIT: You can provide word boundary markers instead of line start/end markers, which is a little more generic. `\b` will mark a word boundary (in Perl - see [Perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - but equivalents exist in other languages)

Comment: How about adding word boundaries instead of the start-of-line and end-of-line markers?

Comment: Yes - I think would be useful. I'll modify to suggest this

Comment: A shameless attempt at votemongering! But that would make sense. Done

Comment: For Perl, you want \b instead of \w and \W (which match word or non-word characters, not a boundary).  Check the reference you linked to.  :)

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
FS\d{5}
```

`\d` means any digit, and `{5}` means exactly 5 of them.

Comment: shouldn't you add something like \D to prevent a sixth digit?

Comment: \d will match any Unicode Decimal Digit (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) if used in .NET

Comment: This is the most basic form, and yes, it could be improved. Like for instance, I could have surrounded it with ^$ -- but the question was so vague that I didn't want to add possibly extraneous elements.

Comment: you are right - the question can be interpreted as "six digits are not possible"

Answer (score 6):

If the exact word should be matched don't forget word boundaries:

```
\bFS\d{5}\b
```

Depending on the language chosen the [syntax for a word boundary might differ](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 1):

FS[0-9]{5}

Answer (score 1):

Only 5 numbers means 0-5 numbers?

```
FS[0-9]\{1,5\}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that if FS00000 is part of other text and doesn't occupy the entire line, you should surround the `FS\d{5}` pattern by word boundaries rather than line boundaries:

```
\bFS\d{5}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^FS[0-9]{5}$
```

will do the trick.

This matches any string that begins (^) with FS followed by 5 times 0-9 and then ends ($).

Don't use \d in this case since it will also match [Unicode Decimal Digits](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) (at least in .NET).